# Can't pass data from controller to blade template laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In my page controller I have

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('authentication/login')->with('page_title','title');
```

I am using a blade file for my template.  In the head of the html, I have

```
<title>{{$page_title}}</title>
```

I get an error that `$page_title` is undefined.

What I want ideally is a `$data=array('page_title'=>'Login','second_item'=>'value')...`.  But as I cannot get the basic passing of a variable to a view working, I am sticking with that first of all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, as @Gravy pointed out, but judging by the way she is trying to write the code, the solution would be:

```
$data = array();
$this->layout->with('data', $data);
$this->layout->content = View::make('home');
```

See more here: http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=58548#p58548

Comment: this works for me, thanks.  I tried adding the line `$this->layout->with($this->data);` in the `_construct` method, so I didn't have to declare it in every controller, but it came back with an error - `Call to a member function with() on a non-object`.  Inside the individual controller function it's fine though.  Do you know why it doesn't see it as an object in the construct function?

Comment: I think you can use View::share() to pass data to the view from the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

```
$data = 
[
    'page_title' => 'Login',
    'second_item' => 'value'
    ...
];

return View::make('authentication/login', $data);

// or

return View::make('authentication/login', compact('data'));

// or

return View::make('authentication/login')->with($data);

// or

return View::make('authentication/login')->with(['page_title' => 'Login', 'second_item' => 'value']);

// or

return View::make('authentication/login')->with(array('page_title' => 'Login', 'second_item' => 'value'));
```

Comment: return View::make('authentication/login')->with('data', $data);

Comment: You could do that @kaning but then you will need to access all elements within view from $data. e.g. `{{ $data['page_title'] }}`. Doing my 2nd option, you can just do this within view `{{ $page_title }}`

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = array('page_title'=>'Login','second_item'=>'value');
return View::make('authentication/login', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

So to get layouts working in controllers you need to first declare the variable `content` in the layout blade template.

In your controller do what you have done already, but remember dot notation when working with directory structures in views. layouts.master is the same as layouts/master.blade.php.

```
class UserController extends BaseController {
    /**
     * The layout that should be used for responses.
     */
    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

    public function getIndex()
    {
        // Remember dot notation when building views
        $this->layout->content = View::make('authentication.login')
                                     ->with('page_title','title');
    }
}
```

in **layouts/master.blade.php**

```
<div class="content">
    {{-- This is the content variable used for the layout --}}
    {{ $content }}
</div>
```

in **authentication/login.blade.php**

```
<title>{{ $page_title }}</title>
```

This will work if you use this structure.

Comment: I get the `$content` variable echoing fine.  It's the $page_title that doesn't echo.  Also, why dot notation and not '/' between folders?